# Bitcoins disappeared on import into Electrum

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, synchronization, electrum

A few years ago I received some bitcoin in Bitcoin Core (~0.4 BTC). Then I transferred some to Kraken (~0.1 BTC) and a few weeks later transferred some back (~0.1 BTC). Then I backed up wallet.dat and formatted that computer.

Now I wanted to sell these bitcoins. I opened the wallet by putting wallet.dat into the correct directory and then running bitcoin-qt -rescan. Bitcoin Core is not synchronized. For some reason it only shows the initial inward transaction of ~0.4 BTC (even that time range is not yet synchronized), but not the other ones.

Then I used listaddressgroupings, which gave me one address and used dumpprivkeys to export the private key for it. I pasted that private key into Electrum. After synchronizing, Electrum shows the initial inward transaction of ~0.4 BTC, but also an outward transaction of the entire sum 2 months later.

Stealing my wallet.dat would have been extremely difficult, because my computer is encrypted and I strictly run Debian with only software from the official repository. Even if the money got stolen the smaller transactions to and from Kraken should show up in Bitcoin Core and Electrum.

I'm a software developer, but I don't know how Bitcoin works specifically. Does anyone have any ideas what could have happened to my Bitcoins?

Comment: The change from the 0.4BTC and the transfer back would have gone to different addresses. They should also be stored in your backup of the wallet.dat, but you wouldn't have imported them to Electrum if you only did the one key. You could wait to see if the other transactions show up if you wait for a bit more synchronization to happen. (Especially if they were apart a large time.) Otherwise you may have an incomplete backup.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Maybe listaddressgroupings doesn't actually give all addresses then. Is there a way to extract all addresses for which there is a private key stored from a wallet.dat?